# How to make SAS Log information appear in Excel file

Tags: sql, sas

I need to create a table that keeps track of my SAS Job. It should get add a new row everytime I run the job without deleting the previous record as below. Also the information here should contain the following information:

```
obs Report ID   User     Start time          End Time      Duration     #of Records
1   328        st150    1/2/2017 16:39      1/2/2017 16:42  02:21   1,231,531,321
2   325        st123    1/2/2017 16:40      1/2/2017 16:41  01:25   231,361,546
3   326        vt125    1/2/2017 16:41      1/2/2017 16:48  07:29   32,654,642
4   328        vt126    2/2/2017 13:22      2/2/2017 13:26  04:23   1,231,531,131
5   326        st150    2/2/2017 13:30      2/2/2017 13:35  05:11   32,653,942
6   329        st320    2/3/2017 13:32      2/3/2017 13:39  07:15   3,562,626,464
```

Everytime the report is run this table needs to add the next row with the above information in that table. Is it doable in SAS? IF so, Can anyone help me in getting to know how?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Add a step in your job to insert a record into the table and calculate the relevant stats. Are you using some type of process manager? How are you scheduling/running your 'jobs'? This would be a SAS table  in your DB and then export to Excel if desired.

Comment: Hello Reeza, Thank you for your time. I am not using any process manager and the job is not scheduled. I am just running it myself. I am little confused on how to get the start time ,end time and the number of observations for the final table that appears in log to extract as an excel table? Also, can we create a program like that so that we can Include that program for others as well?Thank you

Comment: Then basically you need to build it from scratch unfortunately, and I don't think there's an easy way to add that into other programs. One thing to look at is PROC SCAPROC to see if the information provided using this is satisfactory.

Comment: See some of the ideas and code here: http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/279-2010.pdf. Since this isn't a SO question, consider reposting it on communities.sas.com or SAS-L. Or focus the topic on a specific question here. Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am looking at those paper you suggested. Hope it works well.